# item count of datalist that is inside a datalist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datalist

I'm trying to get the item count from a datalist that sits inside a datalist.  I thought this is how I would do it but its returning null. (aspx code condensed for readability)

```
<asp:DataList id="searchResultsProductDataList" runat="server" >
 <asp:DataList ID="productDataList" runat="server">
 </asp:DataList>
</asp:DataList>
```

Here is the code-behind

```
DataList resultnumberDL = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("productDataList");
LiteralTest.Text = resultnumberDL.Items.Count.ToString()
```

I've also tried

```
DataList resultnumberDL = ((DataList)FindControl("productDataList"));
LiteralTest.Text = resultnumberDL.Items.Count.ToString()
```

This is how I would go about doing this right?

Comment: Where are perfoming the count? OnLoad? OnPreRender? Also, the child DataList should go into an ItemTemplate tag

Comment: i understand it should go into an itemtemplate tag and it is. I removed some code for readability.  The count is being performed onItemDataBound.

Comment: And how are you DataBinding the child DataList control?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done like this in `DataList1_ItemDataBound`

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Label PriceLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("PriceLabel");
        Label SalePrice = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("SalePrice");

        //
        // Do you calculations here ..
        //

        SalePrice.Text = "Your Final Value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe double-check your syntax...

If your `ASP.NET` controls are structured like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="dl1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:DataList ID="dl2" runat="server" Enabled="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                ...
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and your `C#` code-behind for the nested `DataList` like this:

```
protected void dl1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataList dl2 = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("dl2");
    ... // load DataTable
    dl2.DataSource = dt;
    dl2.DataBind();
}
```

in this case `e.Item.FindControl("[id]")` will find your nested `DataList`